# Cannot get selected value of datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have a datalist and am trying to get the value that is currently selected when a button is clicked. I have followed exactly what other posts on Stack Overflow have suggested and it doesn't seem to work. In my code you can see what I have tried. It just keeps logging out undefined. When I log the length it does correctly log out that there are 5 options Here is my HTML code

```
<form>
     <input list="slots" name="slot"></input>
     <datalist id="slots">
           {
            this.state.slots.map((slot) => <option value={slot.id} >{slot.start_time} - {slot.end_time}</option>)
           }
      </datalist>
      <Button onClick={() => {this.handleAddFacilitator()}}>Submit</Button>
</form>
```

Here is the method:

```
 handleAddFacilitator(e) {
  console.log($('#slots').val(), "slotID")
  console.log(document.getElementById('slots').value, "second slot")
  console.log(document.getElementById("slots").options.length, "LENGTH")
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The selection takes place in the input element, not the datalist. You need to give the input an ID

```
<input list="slots" name="slot" id="slotsInput"></input>
```

and query the value there:

```
console.log($('#slotsInput').val(), "slotID")
```

See also here: [Get selected value in datalist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844373/get-selected-value-in-datalist-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a select ref type

```
<select ref="slotType">
  <option value="01">one</option>
  <option value="02">two</option>
  <option value="03">three</option>
</select>
```

your button entry

```
<Button onClick={this.handleAddFacilitator}>Submit</Button>

handleAddFacilitator() {
  if (this.refs.slotType) {
    console.log("selected option ==>",this.refs.imageType.value);
  }
}
```

---

another way :

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'PNG'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.print = this.print.bind(this);
  }

  print() {
    if (this.state.value) {
      console.log(this.state.value);
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select ref="slotType" onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <option value="01">one</option>
      <option value="02">two</option>
      <option value="03">three</option>
    </select>
<Button onClick={this.print}>Submit</Button>
      </div
    );
  }
}
```